# Solr SimplePostTool Usage Confusion

Tags: apache, solr

WINDOWS 10 -- SOLR 7.5.0 -- JDK 11.0.1 -- JRE1.8.0_191 -- SIMPLEPOSTTOOL 5.0.0

**I HAVE POSTED THE SOLUTION BELOW; USER: FamousAv8er**

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://factorpad.com/tech/solr/tutorial/solr-schema.html) to understand more about Solr. Unfortunately I cannot seem to understand how I need to structure my statement to make the POST successful.
I have tried multiple commands to try and Post, here are a few

```
C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example>java -jar post.jar films.xml
Error: Unable to access jarfile post.jar

C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example>java -jar /exampledocs/post.jar /films/films.xml
Error: Unable to access jarfile /exampledocs/post.jar

C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example>java -jar exampledocs/post.jar films/films.xml
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Specifying either url or core/collection is mandatory.
Usage: java [SystemProperties] -jar post.jar [-h|-] [<file|folder|url|arg> [<file|folder|url|arg>...]]
```

How should I structure this command to get a successful Post? 
I have also tried editing permissions and unblocking the associated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final solution to my issue using the SimplePostTool:

**TO BE NOTED FOR OTHERS:**

- Run this command from C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example so that the pathways to the files can be done more easily. Also the system doesnt seem to recognize a full pathway.
- Check permissions and that all files accessed are unblocked.
- Use the following syntax:

**java -Dc=YourCoreName -jar exampledocs/post.jar films/films.xml**

```
C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example>java -Dc=films -jar exampledocs/post.jar films/films.xml
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/films/update using content-type application/xml...
POSTing file films.xml to [base]
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/films/update...
Time spent: 0:00:02.392
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the syntax for the `post.jar` by running it as follow:

`cd C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example\exampledocs
java -jar post.jar -h`

I believe you need to pass the name of the Solr core that you want to update, something along these lines:

`cd C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example\exampledocs
java -Dc=name-of-your-core -jar post.jar c:/full/path/to/films.xml`

I seem to remember that on Windows I had to copy the file to import (`films.xml` in your case) to the same folder where the `post.jar` file is located (`C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\example\exampledocs` in your case) but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My issue came from not including the "-Dc=films" as well as trying to use full pathways to files.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -Dc=gettingstarted -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\*.xml
```

Run this command inside solr folder. It gave the following output.

```
C:\opt\solr-5.2.1>java -Dc=gettingstarted -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\*.xml
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update using content-type application/xml...
POSTing file gb18030-example.xml to [base]
POSTing file hd.xml to [base]
POSTing file ipod_other.xml to [base]
POSTing file ipod_video.xml to [base]
POSTing file manufacturers.xml to [base]
POSTing file mem.xml to [base]
POSTing file money.xml to [base]
POSTing file monitor.xml to [base]
POSTing file monitor2.xml to [base]
POSTing file mp500.xml to [base]
POSTing file sd500.xml to [base]
POSTing file solr.xml to [base]
POSTing file utf8-example.xml to [base]
POSTing file vidcard.xml to [base]
14 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Time spent: 0:00:22.043
```

Comment: This is correct but only if you wish to post every .xml file in example/exampledocs/

Comment: I gave a generic solution. wild card needs to replaced with proper file name if required. Thank you @FamousAv8er

Answer (score 0):

### Sometimes there is an issue reading the path of the post.jar file.

In the tutorial it says the command is:  java -jar /exampledocs/post.jar /films/films.xml

Instead give the full path:
java -jar C:\Program Files\solr-8.6.1\example\films\post.jar films.xml

**This worked for me**